# Getting indices of a sorted list of lists in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of lists called `test` and I am trying to get the array locations when the elements of `test` are sorted in an increasing order. For example, I am looking for `ans` for a sample `test` as shown below.

```
test=[[1,2],[3,4]]
ans=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
```

The array locations of `1,2,3,4` are as described in the `ans` above. Any suggestions? I can use a numpy array instead of a list of lists if that makes the job easier.

Comment: Is test always a square matrix? Also, if the matrix is not initially sorted then it's probably better to provide a test example that's not pre-sorted. I presume it's not pre-sorted, otherwise the solution would appear to be trivial.

Comment: @jarmod Yes, it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right. You can *flatten* your list to a list with indices and then sort it (assuming the `test` isn't pre-sorted):

```py
test = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

out = [
    l
    for _, l in sorted(
        ((v, [i, j]) for i, l in enumerate(test) for j, v in enumerate(l))
    )
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```